# Aiming to develop a tensorflow model that differentiates between various faces

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

So I am attempting to use a tensorflow model that is able to classify images of faces and makes a judgement on the type of face being shown (condition x or not condition x). I have 2 datasets, around 5000 images of patients without condition x and 500 images of patients with condition x. I was planning on using tensorflow to develop this image classifier, but I do not know how to approach this issue or where to start since I am new to this field. I was wondering if someone could guide me on where I can find a tutorial on where to start and what to do.

I only have about 5 days or so to do this, so if the time constraint makes a difference that might be helpful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use [Keras](https://keras.io/) and not Tensorflow directly. You will find plenty of starter examples, tutorials and resources with Keras, and for your purposes it should suffice no problem. Keras provides a high level API for the Tensorflow (or CNTK or Theano) backend. If you need to tweak the pre-defined models (e.g., for serious control over the model structure or for academic research) then you need to use the framework directly. But for most cases, you don't need this level of control and you'll find the high-level API of Keras easy and intuitive to use. So for a simple image classification task (e.g., use a CNN), this should work just fine. I'd suggest you also read up on initialising the weights of your network with pre-trained weights to help with your classification task.

For example a quick search came up with a blog post such as [this](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html.).